# Can "à moins que" be used as a subtle, indirect way to ask for something?

Tags: questions, formulation-idiomatique

I’m not sure how the following sentences sound, compared to straightforwardly asking someone to do something with "can you, will you, please" etc.

> Je vais aller à la gare à pied.
>
> 1. À moins que vous ne me conduisiez là ?
> 2. À moins que vous n'ayez l'amabilité de me conduire là ?
> 3. À moins que vous ne me conduisiez là...
> 4. À moins que vous n'ayez l'amabilité de me conduire là...

Comment: à moins que + subjonctif = sauf si + indicatif. C'est factuel. Ce n'est pas une tournure particulière pour demander, mais l'interlocuteur peut comprendre ça.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, *ne me conduisiez là* is not idiomatic, that should be *ne m'y conduisiez*.

With *à moins que vous me conduisiez là*, you are somewhat rude because it is very clear you are asking but you are missing a *formule de politesse*. I wouldn't say that unless I'm familiar with the listener.

You are more polite with adding *vous n'ayez l'amabilité* but depending on the context, it might be "too formal".

This is how I would ask using *à moins que* :

- *Je vais aller à la gare à pied à moins que vous puissiez m'y conduire.* (formal)
- *Je vais aller à la gare à pied à moins que ça ne vous/te dérange pas de m'y conduire.* (informal)

Comment: To keep the same sentence and not ask directly your interlocutor, you could replace "vous puissiez" by "quelqu'un puisse". This way, your need is known and if your interlocutor is in the mood to drive you, (s)he will. If (s)he's not, then (s)he won't feel obligated.

Comment: @Kii Yes, that's a possibility. However, if the only potential person that might be in a position to drive you to the station is your interlocutor, that's still not that subtle.